# Accessor - Get and Set with different values

Tags: c#, winforms

I want the value Administrator advisor .

```
public bool Administrador { get; set; }
```

The user I'm using for the test is true , or is an ADM . The SET Administrator is assigned a Reader 's seat

```
Administrador = reader.GetBoolean(4);
```

On the Debug he Attaches smoothly the value TRUE to the SET .. but when it comes in the code below , and he goes to the GET to get the value , the variable this to FALSE.

```
    if (conta.Administrador)
{
    if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text != "Administrador")
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tbpAdministrador);
    }
    else
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your property name is `Administrador`, but you are assigning to a variable named `Administrator`.  Is this an error in the question, or is it possible you are assigning to the wrong target?

Comment: Oh, sorry drf. Is this an error in the question. Fixed, thx

Answer (score 1):

You're not indenting and you also not srounding your conditions with curly brackets `{ }` which is a recepie for bugs, as you posted.

With indenting alone you could easy spot the problem, which is the `else` condition should have been inside the scope (curly brackets)

```
if (conta.Administrador)
{
    if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text != "Administrador")
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tbpAdministrador);
}
else
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(0);
```

And then you could fix it to

```
if (conta.Administrador)
{
    if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text != "Administrador")
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tbpAdministrador);
    else
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

And then make it prettier and immune to those kind of bugs, like this:

```
if (conta.Administrador)
{
    if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text != "Administrador")
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tbpAdministrador);
    }
    else
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, except [for the difference between than and then](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/than_then.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback been fixed .
But , still not working.
Even conta.Administrador being TRUE, else falls into .